# Getting mouse events to function on dynamically loaded elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple mouseover event that I am trying to work on elements that are loaded with ajax.  For example I have a div that when you mouseover hide/show another div.  When I load these divs through ajax they no longer work.  For example :

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="something">MOUSEOVER</div>
    <div class="else" style="display: none" >HI</div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    //using on hoping to catch the mouse events
    $('.block').on('mouseenter',function(){
        $(this).children('.else').fadeIn('fast');
    });
    $('.block').on('mouseleave',function(){
        $(this).children('.else').fadeOut('fast');
    });
});
```

This works fine straight up like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/RwZWP/) :

But when I load those elements from another page :

```
$j('#trigger').load( url + " .block");
```

The mouse events are no longer recognized.  I thought this is what `live`, `on`, `delegate` were for.  Can someone help me figure this out please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to change your code like:

```
var myFunc = function() {
    $('.block').on('mouseenter',function(){
        $(this).children('.else').fadeIn('fast');
    });
    $('.block').on('mouseleave',function(){
        $(this).children('.else').fadeOut('fast');
    });
}

$('#trigger').load(url + " .block", function() {
    myFunc();
});
```

to make this functions like mouseenter or mouseleave in the loaded content possible.

The other possibility is [$.live();](http://api.jquery.com/live/). Like:

```
$('.block').live('mouseenter', function() {
   //here your code
});
```

Comment: `live` is deprecated. If using jQuery 1.7+ use `on`, and if not use `delegate`. The OP already mentioned `on` in the question so it's probably safe to assume it's available. Your first method should work well though.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what methods like `on` and `delegate` can be used for, but they have to be used correctly.

As events bubble from the element on which they originated up through the DOM you need to capture the event on an ancestor element that already existed:

```
$(".someAncestor").on("mouseenter", ".something", function() {
    //Executed when .something triggers the mouseenter event
});
```

It looks like you are loading the entire `.block` element via AJAX, so you will need to bind the event somewhere higher up the DOM tree (probably the element inside which you append `.block`).

Answer (score 0):

You can put the trigger event to load on AJAX success.